# Vlookup not giving correct results while using average of three equal numbers

Tags: excel, average, vlookup

[image]I'm facing a unique situation. I have a table with two columns - GM% and Payout%. While applying Vlookup on a value that's been derived by an average of three equal numbers, I'm getting #N/A even though when I use vlookup on the individual numbers, I get perfect results.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Please update your question and show us your vlookup formula.

Comment: done. Please see now.

Comment: most likely it's an issue due to rounding. What is the exact value in GM% for 39%? Or is it 0.39 formatted as percent?

Comment: it 0.39 formatted as percent

Comment: Same for cell G3?

Comment: G3 is derived from the average of F2:H2, all three of which are 0.39 formatted as %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to round the result of the AVERAGE to the precision of your base data (GM%):

`= ROUND(AVERAGE(F2:H2),2)`

Comment: Sir! You just saved my life. Thanks so so much *bows*

Comment: Please accept the answer - then everyone knows it is solved. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)